# How to programmatically set the "selected with callout" state for a MapKit marker pin

Tags: ios, mapkit

In 2017 `MKMarkerAnnotationView` was announced to replace `MKPinAnnotationView`. As described by this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/) at 12:21, `MKMarkerAnnotationView` has three states:

1. Normal
2. Selected
3. Selected with Callout

How do you programmatically set the "Selected with Callout" state so that it displays as it does in the WWDC video? This seems like it should be a super straight forward thing to do, but I see absolutely nothing in the MapKit documentation, the only way I can get it to work reliably is this:

[image]

Documentation Links:

1. [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview)
2. [MKMarkerAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview)

Comment: May be this link help you : http://sweettutos.com/2016/03/16/how-to-completely-customise-your-map-annotations-callout-views/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `canShowCallout` property.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true

        let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView

    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    return pinView
}
```

And you need to select the annotation to set the "Selected with Callout" state.

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```